# Meaning of symbol $:=$

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

Can anyone tell me the meaning of this symbol  $:=$

I couldn't find it online. It came up while I was studying joint probability of Gaussian random variables.

[image]

Comment: $:=$ means "defined as"

Comment: The LHS **is defined** by the RHS

Comment: So it is not equal to RHS, but defined by RHS. Meaning?

Comment: It is equal to RHS *because* it's defined by RHS.

Comment: Does that mean I can replace ':=' with '='

Comment: It is equal to RHS, but the equality is simply a consequence of the definition.  In giving pseudocode for an algorithm this symbol may be used to denote an *assignment* of value to variable.

Comment: It can be replaced (and should be) by "Let $c_2=\dots$" or some equivalent phrase.

Comment: Google list of mathematical symbols under Wikipedia if you ever get stuck.

Comment: It would be appropriate to mark the given answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

As commenters said, this symbol is sometimes used to emphasize that equality holds by definition: specifically, the left hand side is defined to be the right hand side. You could find it in Wikipedia's [list of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols).